# passing parameter to oracle query

Tags: c#, oracle

I am getting the ip address of the server i am working on then passing the detected ip to another method which get the office code from table contains list of each office and its ip under oracle database my problem with passing 
the ip to the query in method 2 please help

**method 1**

```
     private IPAddress Get_CurrentLocalIPAddress()
    {
        if (!System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to detect IP Address","Network Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return null;
        }

        IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());

        return host.AddressList.FirstOrDefault(ip => ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
    }
```

**method 2**

```
       public void Find_OfficeCode()
    {
        string oradb = "User Id=user;Password=pwd;";
        string commandStr = @"select DATABASE_NAME from office where UPPER(IP_ADDRESS)=:pOfficeIP";

        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb))
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(commandStr,conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("pOfficeIP", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = Get_CurrentLocalIPAddress().ToString();

            conn.Open();
            IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();                
                label3.Text = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("DATABASE_NAME")).ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not good enough

```
  string oradb = "User Id=user;Password=pwd;";
```

you need to add "Data Source"

```
string oradb = "Data Source=<XXXXXX>;User Id=user;Password=pwd";
```

Here, you don't need "UPPER"

```
UPPER(IP_ADDRESS)=:pOfficeIP";
```

because this is IP address that usually numbers and dots - `123.345.567.789`. And even if you need for some reason, do this

```
UPPER(IP_ADDRESS)=UPPER(:1);
```

And when you add parameter - do

```
conn.Parameters.AddWithValue(":1", "my string")
```

And since you return single value - use `ExecuteScalar`

```
string ip = cmd.ExecuteScalar() As string
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip)). . . .
```

Or use reader. And since you don't abstract your command or connection, there is no reason to abstract reader

```
using (OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.Read())
    {
         label3.Text = reader[0].ToString();
    }
    if (!reader.IsClosed) reader.Close();
}
```